# Only allowing yes or no as an answer

Tags: c#, .net

I am a complete newbie and i am stuck on a small problem

I want the user to only be able to have **yes** or **no** as an answer.

This is what I came up with

```
static public bool askBool(string question)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        return Console.ReadLine() == "y";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new FormatException("Only y or n Allowed");
    }
}
```

The problem is entering any other letter then `'y'` will result in false, how can I best solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT (from comment question)

```
try
{
    Console.Write(question);
    return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new FormatException("Please Enter a Number");
}
```

Comment: Another if-statement of course.  And a loop, so you'll keep asking for input until you're happy.  And do consider that this already good enough, users don't expect fancy ux from a console mode app.  Uplifting this to a checkbox is not that hard in C#.

Comment: **You definitely should not use exceptions for this.**
Exceptions are for exceptional things, namely things you can't control in your code such as network connection or 3rd party errors.  
Using exceptions to handle wrong user input is bad practice.  
In fact, it's an example of a [vexing exception.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

Comment: @HansPassant adding a checkbox in a console application? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here the method will only return true or false if user has entered true  or false.If user enters any word the loop will just continue to ask him for input until he enters `y` or `n`

you can give it a try by doing following changes

```
static public bool askBool(string question)
    {
       bool boolToReturn = false;
       Console.Write(question);
       while (true)
       {
          string ans = Console.ReadLine();
          if (ans != null && ans == "y")
          {
              boolToReturn = true;
              break;
          }
          else if ( ans != null && ans == "n")
          {
              boolToReturn = false;
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              Console.Write("Only y or n Allowed");
          }
       }
       return boolToReturn;
    }`
```

> Answer to second question:-

```
`

    public static int askInt(string question)
        {
           Int intToReturn = false;
           Console.Write(question);
           while (true)
           {
              string ans = Console.ReadLine();
              if (int.TryParse(and,out intToreturn))
                  break;
              else
                  Console.Write("Only number Allowed");
           }
           return intToReturn;
        }`
```

Comment: Side note: the entire block `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is *redundant* and can be safely removed

Comment: I kept it there just for general exception

Comment: @Lucifer: But it's not doing any good at the moment. If an exception is thrown, you catch it - and then throw it again. All that's doing is losing stack trace details. Better to just not have a try/catch statement at all.

Comment: If you are not going to *process* the exception, but *rethrow* it only - why do you catch it all? Now you only *spoil* the stack trace

Comment: Agreed @DmitryBychenko DaisyShipton will remove it

Comment: I have edited answer after suggestion made by you guys

Comment: Hey, i am trying to do the same thing with int. Is using try catch that bad of an idea ? because it does catch the error...it doesnt try again thoght. Im confused on when and how to use it. Im not sure how to enter code in comments. So i edited my question above.

Comment: If you want user to only enter number you should is just change the if else condition in accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

I doubt if you want an *exception* to be thrown - there's nothing *exceptional*  if the user puts `OK` instead of `yes`; I suggest to *keep asking* until "yes" or "no" are read:

```
   public static AskBool(string question) {
     while (true) {
       // If we have a question to ask (the question is not empty one)...
       if (!string.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(question)) 
         Console.WriteLine(question); // ... ask it

       // Trim: let be nice and trim out leading and trailing white spaces
       string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

       // Let's be nice and accept "yes", "YES", "Y" etc.
       if (string.Equals(input, "y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
           string.Equals(input, "yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         return true;
       else if (string.Equals(input, "n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
                string.Equals(input, "no", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         return false;

       // In case of wrong user input, let's give a hint to the user
       Console.WriteLine("Please, answer yes or no (y/n)");
     } 
   }
```

Comment: exactly my point ,whats need to throw exception unnecessarily if you can just show a message because Imo coding based on exception is not a good practice

Comment: @Lucifer then why did you still put your loop inside a `try/catch` that only rethrows any encountered exception?

Comment: I am not throwing exception if user enters another value then y or n I am writing the console message and if occurred exception will be throwed just once

Comment: @Lucifer right, but that exception would still be thrown without any `try/catch` block, or wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

A bit more simplified version of Dmitry's answer with `switch` (what I normally do for this kind of scenarios):

```
static public bool askBool(string question)
{  
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write(question);
        var input = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLowerInvariant();
        switch (input)
        {
            case "y":
            case "yes": return true;

            case "n":
            case "no": return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I'd consider changing `.ReadLine()` to `.ReadKey()` because what we really need here is just 'y' or 'n'... One key is enough.

We use `Exception`s mostly for scenarios when unexpected value will lead to some error. We don't throw an exception when we expect user to enter rubbish values and handle them.

Comment: Nice! I suggest adding `.Trim()` before `.ToLowerInvariant();` - spaces esp. *trailing* ones like `"Y "` can be a really nuisance (Ah! Why my answer is not accepted?! I've put **Y**!).

Answer (score 1):

You want to throw the exception, not catch it. Example:

```
static public bool askBool(string question)
{
    Console.Write(question);
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "y")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(input == "n")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else//It's not y or n: throw the exception.
    {
        throw new FormatException("Only y or n Allowed");
    }
}
```

Of course, you must then capture the 'FormatException' where you call this method.

Comment: You're calling `ReadLine` twice, which is definitely not what's intended. (It's easy to fix though.) I'd be tempted to use a switch statement, personally.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (Console.ReadLine() == "n")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else {
              throw new Exception("only y and n allowed...");
            }
```

Comment: Like Carra's answer, this calls `Console.ReadLine` twice. If the user types "n" then "y", this code will claim neither was entered!

Answer (score 0):

Here another idea:

```
public static bool ReadUserYesOrNo()
{
    bool userSaysYes = true;
    Console.Write("Y\b");

    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true); // intercept: true so no characters are printed
        switch (keyPressed.Key) {
            case ConsoleKey.Y:
                Console.Write("Y\b"); // print Y then move cursor back
                userSaysYes = true;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.N:
                Console.Write("N\b"); // print N then move cursor
                userSaysYes = false;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                done = true;
                Console.WriteLine();
                break;
        }
    }
    return userSaysYes;
}
```

This will print the default value Y to the console. By pressing Y or N the user can toggle between the two values. The character in the console output will be overwritten. Pressing 'enter' selects the choice and the method returns the result.